# Why was the Old Wardour Castle not demolished after the English Civil War?

Tags: england, 17th-century, english-civil-war, building, castles

After the English Civil War, some strongholds such as [Corfe Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corfe_Castle) were slighted, that is demolished, by order of Parliament.

Another Royalist castle, the (Old) [Wardour Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardour_Castle) appears to not have been slighted and only sports battle damage. Why was this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Because there was no need to.** During the [English Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Civil_War), the old [Wardour Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardour_Castle) was besieged and largely blown up by the [3rd Baron Arundell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Arundell,_3rd_Baron_Arundell_of_Wardour). This is not readily apparent from the Wikipedia article, which depicts this photo:

[image: Old Wardour Castle, near Tisbury, Wiltshire, UK.]
<sup>(Photo by [Simon Burchell](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Simon_Burchell) [CC BY_SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0))</sup>

Well, that seems formidable enough. **However - if you walk around the castle, you'll see this:**

[image: Old Wardour Castle]
<sup>Photo by [Mystery Cat](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Mystery_Cat&action=edit&redlink=1) [CC BY_SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)</sup>

As you can see, that's pretty much a ruin. There was no need for Parliament to order it [slighted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slighting) because it was already essentially demolished by the fighting. When the Arundell family recovered in fortunes, they ended up building [a new castle altogether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Wardour_Castle).